How to see Samsung S24 phone on Windows
When I connect my Samsung S20 to Windows via USB, Windows' File Explorer can see the phone, and I can transfer some files.
I have just purchased an Samsung S24.  I cant see it on Windows.

I turned on developer mode
I switched default mode for USB to "transfer files"
I have also enabled USB debugging
I have looked at device manager - there are no issues.
I have run Driver Easy with the phone plugged in - it does not find any drivers to update.

Yet, I can not see my S24.  Previous phones S20, S9 and a friends S22 all work fine.
Windows can't see it.

Check Windows Device manager for USB devices with yellow exclamation mark. If that is the case you are missing the correct drivers.
